# Show that for every $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ with rank(A)=1 that $||A||_{op}=||A||_{HS}$. What happens in the general case?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Show that for every $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ with rank(A)=1 that $||A||_{op}=||A||_{HS}$. What happens in the general case?

> Just to clarify the notations:  $||A||_{op}= \sup\left\{\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} : v\in V \mbox{ with
> > }v\ne 0\right\}.$ $\|A\|^2_{HS}={\rm Tr} (A^{T}A) := \sum_{i \in I} \|Ae_i\|^2$

So using this inequality that I proved before:   $\|AB\|_{HS} \leq \|A\|_{\mathrm{op}} \|B\|_{HS} $ If I Substitute B for I I get the weak inequality, but I can't see how rank=1 helps me here..

Any help?

Comment: "op" is operator norm? For what vector norm? "HS" stands for highest singular value? Are you aware that that is the operator norm for the Euclidean vector norm? Or is that last the essence of the task?

Comment: self-answer: No, "HS" stands for Hilbert-Schmidt, in some parts of the world also known as Frobenius norm. And the unspecified vector norm is, presumably, by default the Euclidean norm.